# How can I remap outgoing TCP ports?

Tags: windows-7, port, tcp

Is there any way to remap a TCP port from a program were you not can change the port number?

The program talks on port 4321 and I want it to go out on port 14321 on the local computer.

Comment: Read up on [netsh](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776297%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_1). Disregard for the moment the lack of Windows 7 mention. The command is there. Let us know how you make out.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer(from sttr) mentioned netsh but gave a command that doesn't work, even when you change his delete to an add.

This works though. Amend as you require.

`C:\Users\user>netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4321 connectaddress=10.0.0.50 connectport=47<ENTER>`

And you can use `netstat -aon | find ":4321"` to check that before the command nothing is running on port 4321, and after it, there is a server listening.

Answer (score -2):

```
netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=4321 connectaddress=<need your IP> connectport=14321
```

Comment: Rather than just posting a line of code, could you please explain what that does, exactly? It would help others to adapt this to their own needs, for example.

Comment: I would have assumed [`add`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731068(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_1) is more useful in this situation than `delete`.

Comment: port forwarder and answer)

Comment: What does "port forwarder and answer)" mean? As I said, it'd be great to explain the code you're posting. Also, `delete` really doesn't seem to make sense for me here.

Comment: I supose he does want add but the 3 parameters he has there are listen on port blah, and forward or remap to that IP that PORT

Comment: @OliverSalzburg try it with add it still doesn't work. This works though `C:\Users\user>netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4321 connectaddr
ess=10.0.0.50 connectport=47`